# How do I close a document after using OpenTextFileReader(path) in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a problem overwriting a file I have opened using `OpenTextFileReader(path)` as follows:

```
allstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(path)
stringReader1 = fileReader.ReadLine()
stringReader2 = fileReader.ReadLine()
```

I only need to read the first two lines.
How do I close the file so I can overwrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to **change** those first two lines?

How about?

```
    Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
    Debug.Print(lines(0))
    Debug.Print(lines(1))
    lines(0) = "new line1"
    lines(1) = "new line2"
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, lines)
```

Comment: Can someone give me a good substring extractor, the 'StringReader.read Method (Char[ ], Int32, Int32)' method is giving me a hard time. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Ask another question and give **details** about the string you have, exactly what you want out of it, and how your current code isn't working...

Comment: Why do you need to read all lines and then realize you are only going to change the first two?

Comment: Unless we'ere talking about a fixed width line file, you have to re-write the whole file, which means you have to have all the lines (even if you only want to change the first two).

Answer (score 1):

Seriously?

Call fileReader.Close or I prefer the using clause:

```
    Dim allstring As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(Path)
    Using fileReader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(Path)
        stringReader1 = fileReader.ReadLine()
        stringReader2 = fileReader.ReadLine()
    End Using
```

Good luck,
Tom

Comment: I was about to post the same answer then realized he was in VB and I was in C#.  But Yes he needs to wrap it in a using statement to make sure the connection to the file is disposed and closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Better stick to .NET ways of doing things. As suggested, `Using` clause is better, and you could also save on `My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader`, by passing a `path` directly to a [StreamReader constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy.aspx), like this:

```
Using fileReader As New StreamReader(Path)
  stringReader1 = fileReader.ReadLine()
  stringReader2 = fileReader.ReadLine()
End Using
```

Also, `allstring` is redundant, it's not used anywhere.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone, I haven't used Visual Basic for 6 years now, just needed to do something fast today, and I couldn't find ' fileReader.Close', but I actually changed the code to one of the solutions below. So sorry for the low level question